# What is the difference between local and non-local concurrency?

Tags: concurrency

I was reading the Wikipedia article on Actor model and came across this line-

> ...bridging the chasm between local and nonlocal concurrency.

What is this "non-local" concurrency and how is it different from "local" concurrency?

Answer (score 4):

Local concurrency is defined as "within a system" (e.g. a multi-core CPU), nonlocal concurrency is defined as "between systems" (e.g. multiple systems interconnected by, for example, a web services interface).

The main differences are the required mechanisms on how to move context around and synchronize it - Which is obviously easier when faced with local concurrency.